# supply multiple values to substitution variable in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created the following function for a generic query that is spooled to an xls file:

```sql
spool &filename..xls;

SELECT &variables
FROM &table_name
WHERE &conditional;

spool off;
```

ideally I want the user to be able to enter any amount of variables to the `SELECT` clause and different conditionals to the `WHERE` clause

like this

```sql
SELECT var1,var2,var3....
WHERE var1 = va OR var1 = otherval.....
```

Problem is that PL/SQL will cut off the input, for example if I put

`define variables = var1,var2`

it only takes this `var1,`

I can't really find anything relating on how this can be done in PL/SQL but obviously not the way I'm trying

Comment: Seems like this has less to do with PL/SQL, and more to do with SQL*plus.

Comment: I think I'm confusing the two, new to SQL Plus, I thought PL/SQL was like the type of SQL SQL PLus used

Comment: If your variable contains punctuation or whitespace, enclose it in single quotes, e.g. `define variables = 'var1,var2'`

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language extension of SQL.  Simple queries are SQL, not PL/SQL.  SQL*Plus is the application (one of many you could use) that allows you to execute SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: @kfinity thanks, that solved it. Curious, could you recommend documenation on PL/SQL (unless thit is just a SQL PLUS thing) I could not find anything regarding it

Comment: @AndyDan Thanks, that clears up my confusion

Comment: Sure - `define` is a SQL*Plus command, so you can look it up in that documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve017.htm#SQPUG037

Comment: thanks, I was google PL/SQL so I guess that is why I had so much trouble finding it

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't* define your variables (or define only one) for the SELECT clause, the user can enter a string of multiple comma-separated values.  As long as they are all valid column names, and properly comma-separated, SQL*Plus will substitute the entire string into the query.

I wasn't spooling to a file, though.  Doing `set verify off` before the `spool` command helps some, but you're still going to get prompts like

> Enter value for variables:
>
> Enter value for table_name:
>
> Enter value for conditional:

for each variable.  Probably better to do the "define" before starting to spool the results.

Comment: you're saying if I drop the '''define''' from the script it should work?

Comment: worked for you where? I'm trying to use this as a script within another script; not querying the DB directly. It's needed as I have to query like 10 or so tables like this but the parameters differ slightly, so I wanna call this script 10x with the different parameters set and spool the outputs to excel format

Comment: I just ran your query in SQL*Plus, and used values appropriate to my database.  I edited my answer to allow for the fact that you're spooling the results and don't want to see the prompts in your spool file.

Comment: Basically, you probably still want to use "define", but only define one variable for each & that you have in the original query.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you and I are on the same page here. ```kfinity's``` comment worked for me